# Execute .BAT file from a web page

Tags: file, batch-file, web

I'd like to execute a batch file directly from my app , instead of the command window.

My app is runnng under Apache Tomcat .

I don't know if it's possible or not. But please, If any of you have done something familiar, let me know.

Any hint or help would be highly apreciated.

Comment: So the batch should run on your server? Or on the client using the website? That makes quite a difference...

Comment: @ImaneKtb I updated my answer when I read that you only have HTML and JSP files in your app.

Comment: The app contains html and jsp pages. The batch file is generated from a program (Pentaho Data Integration) that runs under Apache Tomcat. My goal is making it possible to be run through a button for example in my web page.

Comment: @ImaneKtb did you read the answer below? ...

Comment: @ImaneKtb I read that as "on the server". Then have a look at Fernando Garcia's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what language you are using in the backend, I guess if you are using Tomcat, you are running Java. You should do something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start your_bat_path.bat");
```

If you are only using JSP and no Java objects anywhere in your application, you could execute a scriptlet, but **the use of scriptlets is highly discouraged**, you should avoid running anything in your views:

Somewhere inside some JSP file:

```
<%
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start your_bat_path.bat");
%>
```

Instead of that, you should use some MVC pattern and execute that kind of stuff in the controller layer, for example.

Comment: thank you for the tip.

 Actually , my web app has simply  Html/js pages and Jsp page.

The .Bat file is already made from a program (Pentaho Data Integration) that runs java.

In this case, I probably should put the batch file under the server Apache tomcat. 
And to execute it externally from the jsp page , I should be using the classe 'Runtime'
and its method 'exec()'.

 I'm on it , thank you for the indication.

Comment: Yes. You can test the parameter of the `exec()` method in a windows shell (cmd) to see if you wrote the path correctly and you are getting the expected result, the method `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` does the same than if you run the parameter inside `exec()` in the shell.